# How do I apply nested style in production?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In production, all the classes are replaced with "jss" + n: jss1, jss2, jss3 etc.
Unfortunately this breaks custom selectors such as `& $icon`, since the class that starts with "icon" on my local machine is replaced with a "jss" + n class in production.

For example here is a piece of my code:

```
export const styles = {
  active: {
    "& $icon": {
      position: "relative",
    }
  }
}
```

On my machine, the position property is applied. In production, the "icon" class name changes for "jss" + n, making the scss selector `& $icon` useless.

I could avoid using custom scss selectors, but that would be a waste of useful syntax. I could also disable the "jss" renaming, but it seems like a poor work-around to me, that could possibly create other problems and make maintenance harder.

How do I fix this problem in a standard and efficient way?